# Parsor Error: Unexpected token during angular update from 8 to 12

Tags: angular, angular12

I was doing Angular version update from 8 to 12. In which I am getting this build error.

```
error NG5002: Parser error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 2 in [{{maxLength}}]}
```

My component.html error line looks like below

```
<div>
    <span>Characters left: {{maxLength - formInputs.accountStatusReasonComment?.length}}</span>
</div>
```

Is this expressions have any update in Angular 12? Any idea ?

Comment: It looks fine, can you share on stackblitz? Maybe maxLength member is not public.

Answer (score 2):

If the `formInputs.accountStatusReasonComment` is undefined the expression might wind down to `{{maxLength - }}`. With Angular 8 it couldn't be found until runtime, but from Angular 9, Ivy AoT is default rendering engine. And it might find such useful edge case errors.

Instead of safe navigation operator you could try the following

```html
<span>
  Characters left: {{ maxLength - (formInputs.accountStatusReasonComment.length || 0) }}
</span>
```

Here numeric `0` will be used if the `formInputs.accountStatusReasonComment.length` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks Michael i will try this. I have another scenario like {{reasonObject&& reasonObject.settings?reasonobject.settings.okbuttoname:"save changes"}} this one also throwing the error. Any work around for this?

Comment: @NithinPaul: You might have to go one more level down in the short circuit: `{{ (reasonObject && reasonObject.settings && reasonObject.settings.okbuttoname) ? reasonobject.settings.okbuttoname : 'save changes' }}`

Comment: @NithinPaul: If you're using [Angular >=12.0.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1200-2021-05-12), you could straight up use the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) in the template: `{{ reasonobject.settings.okbuttoname ?? 'save changes' }}`.

Comment: Thanks again, i tried 2nd last option, now i am getting this - "Parser error: unexpected token } at column 12 in [{{maxLength}}] ", I given the exact syntax you mentioned

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the 2nd last option. Do you mean the nullisch coalescing operator? Also make sure all the variables accessed in the template (`maxLength`, `formInputs` and `reasonobject`) are `public`.

Comment: Sorry i mean this {{ (reasonObject && reasonObject.settings && reasonObject.settings.okbuttoname) ? reasonobject.settings.okbuttoname : 'save changes' }} . Yes these reasonobject and all are alredy used in this template and we getting this error after upgrade only

Comment: @NithinPaul: Then I don't get the issue. The `maxLength` error is supposed to be solved with the `{{ maxLength - (formInputs.accountStatusReasonComment.length || 0) }}` solution. If the error still persists please try to create a minimal reproducible example using Stackblitz.